# [PYTHON]Quero impedir que para o teste de números iguais na função "if" ele considere quando for "menor que"

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, if

Estava fazendo testes com "É menor ou igual a tal número" e percebi que não sei como impedir que o "menor que" apareça quando um número igual é testado. Eu sei que eu poderia mudar o print do "else" para "print('É menor ou igual a 10')", mas eu gostaria de saber outras forma de fazer isso, como a que eu estava tentando no meu código
Esse é o meu código:

```
valor = int(input())
if valor > 10:
 print('É maior que 10')
else:
 print('É menor que 10')
if valor == 10:
 print('É igual a 10')
```

Exemplo da minha entrada e saída que está dando com o código assim:

```
Entrada:10            Saída:É menor que 10
                            É igual a 10
```

Comment: `if valor > 10: print('É maior que 10') elif valor < 10: print('É menor que 10') else: print('É igual a 10')`

Answer (score 0):

```
valor = int(input())
if valor > 10:
 print('É maior que 10')
elif valor ==10:
 print('é igual a 10')
else:
 print('É menor que 10')
```

Você estava colocando o if dps do else, o else é final de condição. ele gira tudo que vem dps dele, pq se não for a primeiro condicional é tudo dps do else